# Gparted not working correctly

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, xubuntu, gparted

So, I'm using gparted as an application installed with `sudo apt-get install gparted` on Xubuntu 14.0 with MATE.

I'm trying to resize my Mac's hard drive partition down for free space.

### What happens

So, right when I start up gparted via terminal with the command `sudo gparted` it immediately starts spamming the console with these errors.  But keep in mind that the "Source ID" number usually changes every time I run gparted (Normally varies between 1 to 70).  I'm not sure if that's important or not, but the more information the better:

```
(gpartedbin:9634): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 7 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:9634): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 6 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:9634): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 26 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:9634): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 25 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:9634): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 33 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:9634): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 32 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:9634): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 38 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:9634): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 37 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:9634): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 49 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:9634): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 48 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:9634): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 52 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:9634): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 51 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

But after this, everything seems to be fine, seems to operate normal on startup.  So I'd click on my Mac hard drive partition.  In which case you need a picture, my partition list looks like this:

[image]

(Mac's hard drive outlined in red)

I would choose the resize tool, and resize it to `80000 MiB`, after doing so and clicking "Resize", the once I click "Apply" a confirmation box would pop up and I would click something like "Proceed" or "OK" or something like that.  This is where it would freeze.  The window is not closable, nor is any of it operational.

After this I would have to force quit the window, and stop `gparted` and `gpartedbin` with `sudo killall` (via `sudo killall gparted` and `sudo killall gpartedbin`).

### Attempted Solutions

I've removing gparted with `sudo apt-get remove gparted`, and I tried removing it in synaptic.  I've also tried for a purge, `sudo apt-get purge gparted` and a complete removal in synaptic.  After reinstalling after all of these, no success.

On another Ask Ubuntu question I saw that maybe `gksudo gparted` would resolve it, but the same issue proceeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to answers [like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118835/does-linux-support-mac-os-partitions-format), Linux has only partial support of HFS+. You will not be able to resize it from Gparted or any other way, except doing it from Mac. You can only read HFS partition.
The only error of Gparted is that it crushes instead of telling you that this action is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you encountered a bug in the version of GParted packaged for Xubuntu 14.0.  I suggest booting from media containing [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php), of which the most recent version is 0.19.1-4. A newer release is anticipated early next week.